# Writing to files in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, fs

I've been trying to find a way to write to a file when using Node.js, but with no success. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3002, accepted):

There are a lot of details in the [File System API](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html). The most common way is:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
}); 

// Or
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/test-sync', 'Hey there!');
```

Comment: I've tested this script using Node, and I tried changing the file path to "/home/", but I got the following error: `{ [Error: EACCES, open '/home/test.txt'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/home/test.txt' }
` How can I modify this script so that it will work outside of `/tmp`?

Comment: Also note you can use fs.writeFileSync(...) to accomplish the same thing synchronously.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit old, but @AndersonGreen, you need to run node as root or chmod /home properly to allow R/W permissions to current node process owner (your username tough) so you can write the file

Comment: Actually, @DenysVitali, the problem is that jane should not be able to write any files into `/home/...`. Generally that directory is 755 root:wheel (or whatever). If node wants to write a file as jane, it's going to be easier to write to `/home/jane/test.txt`. Changing `/home` to something more permissive than 755 is a huge mistake.

Comment: @JaneAvriette Well, since he wanted to save the file on `/home` directory I suggested to chmod it. I know it could generate a security issue. But well, if the user wants to save there, that's the solution.

P.S: I agree with what you said (:

Comment: Do you need to `fs.close()` when finished?

Comment: At least with ECMAScript 6, `fs.writeFile` is deprecated.  Not sure what has replaced it.

Comment: [**“Note that it is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, `fs.createWriteStream` is strongly recommended.”**](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Comment: Or ES2015 async/await style: `await promisify(fs.writeFile)("./test.md", markdownFile);`

Answer (score 624):

Currently there are three ways to write a file:

1. [`fs.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback`)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)

   You need to wait for the callback to ensure that the buffer is written to disk. It's not buffered.
2. [`fs.writeFile(filename, data, [encoding], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

   All data must be stored at the same time; you cannot perform sequential writes.
3. [`fs.createWriteStream(path, [options]`)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

   Creates a [`WriteStream`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1623), which is convenient because you don't need to wait for a callback. But again, it's not buffered.

A [`WriteStream`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1623), as the name says, is a stream. A stream by definition is “a buffer” containing data which moves in one direction (source ► destination). But a writable stream is not necessarily “buffered”. A stream is “buffered” when you write `n` times, and at time `n+1`, the stream sends the buffer to the kernel (because it's full and needs to be flushed).

**In other words:** “A buffer” is the object. Whether or not it “is buffered” is a property of that object.

If you look at the code, the `WriteStream` inherits from a writable `Stream` object. If you pay attention, you’ll see how they flush the content; they don't have any buffering system.

If you write a string, it’s converted to a buffer, and then sent to the native layer and written to disk. When writing strings, they're not filling up any buffer. So, if you do:

```js
write("a")
write("b")
write("c")
```

You're doing:

```js
fs.write(new Buffer("a"))
fs.write(new Buffer("b"))
fs.write(new Buffer("c"))
```

That’s *three* calls to the I/O layer. Although you're using “buffers”, the data is not buffered. A buffered stream would do: `fs.write(new Buffer ("abc"))`, one call to the I/O layer.

As of now, in Node.js v0.12 (stable version announced 02/06/2015) now supports two functions:
[`cork()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.11.5/api/stream.html#stream_writable_cork) and
[`uncork()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.11.5/api/stream.html#stream_writable_uncork). It seems that these functions will finally allow you to buffer/flush the write calls.

For example, in Java there are some classes that provide buffered streams (`BufferedOutputStream`, `BufferedWriter`...). If you write three bytes, these bytes will be stored in the buffer (memory) instead of doing an I/O call just for three bytes. When the buffer is full the content is flushed and saved to disk. This improves performance.

I'm not discovering anything, just remembering how a disk access should be done.

Comment: +1 - nice explanation.  For write stream, it's important to read the docs carefully.  If returns false or closing, important to call writer.once('drain', function(){}) or I missed lines that hadn't drained when the process ended.

Comment: any chance you could provide an example of how to use `cork()` and `uncork()` for those of us who want to try out the pre-release 0.11 node?

Comment: As of now, Node v0.12 is stable.

Comment: According to an analysis of code from GitHub, fs.writeFile seems to be the most popular of the functions you mentioned. Here are [real world examples for using fs.writeFile](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/fs/writeFile)

Comment: Are there production quality libraries on `npm` implementing buffered writing?

Comment: I have tested createWriteStream on nodejs 14 and it is a lot faster than individual writes. also cork and uncork didn't affect the performance.

Answer (score 313):

You can of course make it a little more advanced. Non-blocking, writing bits and pieces, not writing the whole file at once:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("my_file.txt");
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
  stream.write("My first row\n");
  stream.write("My second row\n");
  stream.end();
});
```

Comment: What is the 'fd' variable passed into the callback for stream.once ?

Comment: @ScottDavidTesler file descriptor so you will be able to close stream after you've done with it.

Comment: When do I close the stream? Why is this non-blocking? Just curious, I am trying to write to a log file.

Comment: You can always do a stream.end() when you've done your stream.writes(). I will add it to the example.

Comment: Will this fail if the server goes down before stream.end() is called? In essence, can I use this for error logging to specific file? (Yes, I know you can specify this when you run the node app, but for certain errors I want to store it in a different file than all the other logging).

Comment: I'm not sure if when the stream is flushed. My guess is that there is a possibility to flush the stream on demand.

Comment: Does the 'open' event happen asynchronously? Do I have to wait for it, or can I start writing into the stream immediately?

Comment: @JoLiss You will have to wait for it.

Comment: This example is leaving me with an empty "my_file.txt" and a dump of the WriteStream object.

Answer (score 110):

**Synchronous Write**

> fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])

```
fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync("foo.txt", "bar");
```

**Asynchronous Write**

> fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)

```
fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('foo.txt', 'bar', (err) => { if (err) throw err; });
```

**Where**

```
file <string> | <Buffer> | <URL> | <integer> filename or file descriptor
data <string> | <Buffer> | <Uint8Array>
options <Object> | <string>
callback <Function>
```

Worth reading the offical File System (fs) [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html).

**Update: async/await**

```
fs = require('fs');
util = require('util');
writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

fn = async () => { await writeFile('foo.txt', 'bar'); }

fn()
```

Comment: How to synchroniously append to a file?

Answer (score 60):

```
var path = 'public/uploads/file.txt',
buffer = new Buffer("some content\n");

fs.open(path, 'w', function(err, fd) {
    if (err) {
        throw 'error opening file: ' + err;
    }

    fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(err) {
        if (err) throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
        fs.close(fd, function() {
            console.log('file written');
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: this demonstrates how to write a file using lower level fs operations.  for example, you can guarantee when the file has finished writing to disk and has released file descriptors.

Comment: Since in this example the offset if set to '0' (= third parameter of `fs.write()`) this example works only if everything is short enough to be written in a single write call.

Answer (score 43):

The answers provided are dated and a newer way to do this is:

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises
await fsPromises.writeFile('/path/to/file.txt', 'data to write')
```

[see documents here for more info](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options)

Comment: @jgraup: are you using the latest version of node?

Comment: Node `v10.15.0`

Comment: @jpraup - latest is Node 12.

Comment: I would just add the requirements in your answer or a note about the warning. The docs say `Added in: v10.0.0` so I would assume it could be used but I see elsewhere on here that people have opted to suppress the warning.

Comment: Enclosing function has to be async or this will not work.

Comment: @Zimano Node already has support for top-level await, you don't need async wrapper.

Comment: For modules: `import FileSystem from "node:fs/promises";`.

Answer (score 35):

I liked *[Index of ./articles/file-system](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system)*.

It worked for me.

See also *[How do I write files in node.js?](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs)*.

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
    if (err) 
        return console.log(err);
    console.log('Wrote Hello World in file helloworld.txt, just check it');
});
```

Contents of helloworld.txt:

```
Hello World!
```

Update:
As in Linux node write in current directory , it seems in some others don't, so I add this comment just in case :
Using this `ROOT_APP_PATH = fs.realpathSync('.'); console.log(ROOT_APP_PATH);` to get where the file is written.

Comment: Where to find the file helloworld.txt ? I can't find it in any folders... thanks.

Comment: in folder that you run the script

Comment: That's weird... I just can't find it anywhere. Will it be hidden? thanks again~

Comment: I just found it. Using this __ROOT_APP_PATH__ = fs.realpathSync('.');
console.log(__ROOT_APP_PATH__); to get my where the file written. Thanks.

Comment: @Sérgio: do we need to close writefile? I am calling another process and I am receiving an error msg regarding file is begin used by some other process.

Answer (score 28):

I know the question asked about "write" but in a more general sense "append" might be useful in some cases as it is easy to use in a loop to add text to a file (whether the file exists or not). Use a "\n" if you want to add lines eg:

```
const fs = require('fs');
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    fs.appendFileSync("junk.csv", "Line:"+i+"\n");
}
```

Comment: Since it's now available I'd recommmend using `const` instead of `var`, i.e. `const fs = require('fs');`, to avoid unwanted side effects, in particular if you are working with a somewhat larger code base.

Answer (score 17):

OK, it's quite simple as Node has built-in functionality for this, it's called `fs` which stands for **File System** and basically, **NodeJS File System module**...

So first require it in your **server.js** file like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

`fs` has few methods to do write to file, but my preferred way is using `appendFile`, this will append the stuff to the file and if the file doesn't exist, will create one, the code could be like below:

```
fs.appendFile('myFile.txt', 'Hi Ali!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Thanks, It\'s saved to the file!');
});
```

Comment: single quote in the string should be escaped.

Answer (score 14):

You may write to a file using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) (file system) module.

Here is an example of how you may do it:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const writeToFile = (fileName, callback) => {
  fs.open(fileName, 'wx', (error, fileDescriptor) => {
    if (!error && fileDescriptor) {
      // Do something with the file here ...
      fs.writeFile(fileDescriptor, newData, (error) => {
        if (!error) {
          fs.close(fileDescriptor, (error) => {
            if (!error) {
              callback(false);
            } else {
              callback('Error closing the file');
            }
          });
        } else {
          callback('Error writing to new file');
        }
      });
    } else {
      callback('Could not create new file, it may already exists');
    }
  });
};
```

You might also want to get rid of this callback-inside-callback code structure by useing **Promises** and `async`/`await` statements. This will make asynchronous code structure much more flat. For doing that there is a handy [util.promisify(original)](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function might be utilized. It allows us to switch from callbacks to promises. Take a look at the example with `fs` functions below:

```js
// Dependencies.
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

// Promisify "error-back" functions.
const fsOpen = util.promisify(fs.open);
const fsWrite = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const fsClose = util.promisify(fs.close);

// Now we may create 'async' function with 'await's.
async function doSomethingWithFile(fileName) {
  const fileDescriptor = await fsOpen(fileName, 'wx');

  // Do something with the file here...

  await fsWrite(fileDescriptor, newData);
  await fsClose(fileDescriptor);
}
```

Comment: Why are these snippets and not pieces of code? They will never be able to run in a browser anyways.

Comment: @Zimano As I understand it the question was regarding nodejs so doesn't need to be able to run in a browser.

Comment: @Manfred Exactly! I think you misunderstood what I was trying to say; there is no point in having snippets since it is nodejs!

Answer (score 14):

**You can write to files with streams.**

Just do it like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const stream = fs.createWriteStream('./test.txt');
stream.write("Example text");
```

Answer (score 11):

Here we use w+ for read/write both actions and if the file path is not found then it would be created automatically.

```
fs.open(path, 'w+', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR !! " + err);
    } else {
        fs.write(data, 'content', 0, 'content length', null, function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log("ERROR !! " + err);
            fs.close(data, function() {
                console.log('written success');
            })
        });
    }
});
```

Content means what you have to write to the file and its length, 'content.length'.

Answer (score 11):

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 fs.writeFile(path + "\\message.txt", "Hello", function(err){
 if (err) throw err;
  console.log("success");
});
```

For example : read file and write to another file :

```
  var fs = require('fs');
    var path = process.cwd();
    fs.readFile(path+"\\from.txt",function(err,data)
                {
                    if(err)
                        console.log(err)
                    else
                        {
                            fs.writeFile(path+"\\to.text",function(erro){
                                if(erro)
                                    console.log("error : "+erro);
                                else
                                    console.log("success");
                            });
                        }
                });
```

Comment: Where you are writting the data into the "to.text"??

Comment: What does this answer add to the multiple already existing answers about `writeFile`?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the sample of how to read file csv from local and write csv file to local.

```
var csvjson = require('csvjson'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient,
    mongoDSN = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
    collection;

function uploadcsvModule(){
    var data = fs.readFileSync( '/home/limitless/Downloads/orders_sample.csv', { encoding : 'utf8'});
    var importOptions = {
        delimiter : ',', // optional 
        quote     : '"' // optional 
    },ExportOptions = {
        delimiter   : ",",
        wrap        : false
    }
    var myobj = csvjson.toSchemaObject(data, importOptions)
    var exportArr = [], importArr = [];
    myobj.forEach(d=>{
        if(d.orderId==undefined || d.orderId=='') {
            exportArr.push(d)
        } else {
            importArr.push(d)
        }
    })
    var csv = csvjson.toCSV(exportArr, ExportOptions);
    MongoClient.connect(mongoDSN, function(error, db) {
        collection = db.collection("orders")
        collection.insertMany(importArr, function(err,result){
            fs.writeFile('/home/limitless/Downloads/orders_sample1.csv', csv, { encoding : 'utf8'});
            db.close();
        });            
    })
}

uploadcsvModule()
```

Comment: This introduces all sorts of complications (MongoClient, JSON etc.) that do not pertain to the question.

Answer (score 6):

> #### [`fs.createWriteStream(path[,options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)
>
> `options` may also include a `start` option to allow writing data at some position past the beginning of the file. Modifying a file rather than replacing it may require a `flags` mode of `r+` rather than the default mode `w`. The encoding can be any one of those accepted by [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer).
>
> If `autoClose` is set to true (default behavior) on `'error'` or `'finish'` the file descriptor will be closed automatically. If `autoClose` is false, then the file descriptor won't be closed, even if there's an error. It is the application's responsibility to close it and make sure there's no file descriptor leak.
>
> Like [ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream), if `fd` is specified, [WriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream) will ignore the `path` argument and will use the specified file descriptor. This means that no `'open'` event will be emitted. `fd` should be blocking; non-blocking `fd`s should be passed to [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket).
>
> If `options` is a string, then it specifies the encoding.

After, reading this long article. You should understand how it works.
So, here's an example of `createWriteStream()`.

```
/* The fs.createWriteStream() returns an (WritableStream {aka} internal.Writeable) and we want the encoding as 'utf'-8 */
/* The WriteableStream has the method write() */
fs.createWriteStream('out.txt', 'utf-8')
.write('hello world');
```

Comment: `createWriteStream` was already mentioned in [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958773/1269037) answer [years before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368255/1269037) this one.

Answer (score 6):

Point 1:

If you want to write something into a file.
means: it will remove anything already saved in the file and write the new content. use **fs.promises.writeFile()**

Point 2:

If you want to append something into a file.
means: it will not remove anything already saved in the file but append the new item in the file content.then first read the file, and then add the content into the readable value, then write it to the file. so use **fs.promises.readFile and fs.promises.writeFile()**

---

example 1: I want to write a JSON object in my JSON file .

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = {table:[{id: 1, name: 'my name'}]}
const file_path = './my_data.json'
writeFile(file_path, data)
async function writeFile(filename, writedata) {
  try {
    await fs.promises.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(writedata, null, 4), 'utf8');
    console.log('data is written successfully in the file')
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('not able to write data in the file ')
  }
}
```

---

example2 :
if you want to append data to a JSON file.
you want to add data **{id:1, name:'my name'}** to file **my_data.json** on the same folder root. just call **append_data (file_path , data )** function.

It will append data in the JSON file if the file existed . or it will create the file and add the data to it.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = {id: 2, name: 'your name'}
const file_path = './my_data.json'
append_data(file_path, data)

async function append_data(filename, data) {

  if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
    var read_data = await readFile(filename)
    if (read_data == false) {
      console.log('not able to read file')
    } else {
      read_data.table.push(data)  //data must have the table array in it like example 1
      var dataWrittenStatus = await writeFile(filename, read_data)
      if (dataWrittenStatus == true) {
        console.log('data added successfully')
      } else {
        console.log('data adding failed')
      }
    }
  }
}

async function readFile(filePath) {
  try {
    const data = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')
    return JSON.parse(data)
  }
  catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

async function writeFile(filename, writedata) {
  try {
    await fs.promises.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(writedata, null, 4), 'utf8');
    return true
  }
  catch (err) {
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use library `easy-file-manager`

install first from npm
`npm install easy-file-manager`

Sample to upload and remove files

```
var filemanager = require('easy-file-manager')
var path = "/public"
var filename = "test.jpg"
var data; // buffered image

filemanager.upload(path,filename,data,function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
});

filemanager.remove(path,"aa,filename,function(isSuccess){
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: `This modules is created to save and remove files.`. Not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can write in a file by the following code example:

```
var data = [{ 'test': '123', 'test2': 'Lorem Ipsem ' }];
fs.open(datapath + '/data/topplayers.json', 'wx', function (error, fileDescriptor) {
  if (!error && fileDescriptor) {
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
    fs.writeFile(fileDescriptor, stringData, function (error) {
      if (!error) {
        fs.close(fileDescriptor, function (error) {
          if (!error) {
            callback(false);
          } else {
            callback('Error in close file');
          }
        });
      } else {
        callback('Error in writing file.');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: `writeFile` had already been given as an answer multiple times, years ago. What does this answer add?

Comment: Also why od you open file? Shouldn't the answer be about writing files?