# How do I read a file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, filesystems, fs

In Node.js, I want to read a file, and then `console.log()` each line of the file separated by `\n`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fs=require('fs');

fs.readFile('/path/to/file','utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var arr=data.split('\n');
  arr.forEach(function(v){
    console.log(v);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the [`fs` module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [File System](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) API's in node.js, there is also few similar questions on SO, there is [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/nodejs-write-to-file)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to read a file in Node. You can learn about all of them in [the Node documentation about the File System module, `fs`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html).

In your case, let's assume that you want to read a simple text file, `countries.txt` that looks like this;

```
Uruguay
Chile
Argentina
New Zealand
```

First you have to `require()` the `fs` module at the top of your JavaScript file, like this;

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Then to read your file with it, you can use the [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) method, like this;

```
fs.readFile('countries.txt','utf8', function (err, data) {});
```

Now, inside the `{}`, you can interact with the results of the `readFile` method. If there was an error, the results will be stored in the `err` variable, otherwise, the results will be stored in the `data` variable. You can log the `data` variable here to see what you're working with;

```
fs.readFile('countries.txt','utf8', function (err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

If you did this right, you should get the exact contents of the text file in your terminal;

```
Uruguay
Chile
Argentina
New Zealand
```

I think that's what you want. Your input was separated by newlines (`\n`), and the output will be as well since `readFile` doesn't change the contents of the file. If you want, you can make changes to the file before logging the results;

```
fs.readFile('calendar.txt','utf8', function (err, data) {
  // Split each line of the file into an array
  var lines=data.split('\n');

  // Log each line separately, including a newline
  lines.forEach(function(line){
    console.log(line, '\n');
  });
});
```

That will add an extra newline between each line;

```
Uruguay

Chile

Argentina

New Zealand
```

You should also account for any possible errors that happen while reading the file by adding `if (err) throw err` on the line right before you first access `data`. You can put all of that code together in a script called `read.js` like this;

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('calendar.txt','utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // Split each line of the file into an array
  var lines=data.split('\n');

  // Log each line separately, including a newline
  lines.forEach(function(line){
    console.log(line, '\n');
  });
});
```

You can then run that script in your Terminal. Navigate to the directory that contains both `countries.txt` and `read.js`, and then type `node read.js` and hit enter. You should see the results logged out on the screen. Congratulations! You've read a file with Node!