# Write to file using JavaScript on macOS

Tags: javascript, macos, writetofile

How I can write simple text (e.g. "Hello world") to file? I must use JavaScript and code must work on Mac OS.

Comment: Using what JavaScript environment? Node.js? Something else?

Comment: Why is this tagged "java"? There is no sign of anything related to that language in the question.

Comment: Why is this tagged "ios" and "macbook"? Are you dealing with iOS or OS X? There are significant differences between them.

Comment: I have only one *.js file. I use UIAutomation for write my test scripts. And I don't know how I can write to file. I novice in this.

Comment: Sorry for adding unnecessary tags

Answer (score 1):

Security limitations don't allow javascript to access the local file system through the browser.
But you can use the [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) interpreter to run javascript "server side".
If this is the case, your code should look something [like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/nodejs-write-to-file)

Comment: Mac OS X Version 10.6.8.
The problem:  MacOS has a software-as-UIAutomation so he takes .app and .js. When just runs only it start the emulator and runs the script ... So for example use the script I take the data and I want to write to a file. Seems simple ... but I do not know how.