# Write libxmljs XML in to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, libxml-js

I have a libxmljs XML object. I want to write it to a file; here is so far what I have.

```
var libxml = require('libxmljs');
var xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
           '<root>' +
               '<child foo="bar">' +
                   '<grandchild baz="fizbuzz">'+
            '<blah>grandchild content<inblah>blah blah</inblah></blah>' +
            '<blah1>grandchild content blah2</blah1>'+
           '</grandchild>' +
               '</child>' +
             '</root>';


var xmlDoc = libxml.parseXml(xml);
//..... do some changes to xmlDoc
console.log(xmlDoc.toString());
```

I want to write `xmlDoc` to a separate file. Such as `result.xml`

Comment: You should take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2897619/589985) - the first three answers are all possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks @XavierHolt but that doesn't seem to be help. I'm using NodeJS library. So I need to find a solution which can be used in NodeJS.

Comment: Whoops!  Thought it was running in the browser...  Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2496710/589985) instead.

Comment: yeah. sorry I did not mention it in my question. I found a solution from your link. thank you so much @XavierHolt.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built in fs module in node.js. Like this:

```
var js = require('fs');
var libxml = require('libxmljs');
var xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>foobar</root>';

var xmlDoc = libxml.parseXml(xml);
//..... do some changes to xmlDoc
fs.writeFile('test.xml', xmlDoc.toString(), function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Wrote XML string to test.xml'); 
});
```

You can read further about the fs module here: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback