# Error When Trying to Out Prime Numbers in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

**I'm writing a node.js script that writes the first 100 prime numbers to a file, with each prime separated by a comma.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
function listPrimes( max ) {
    var primes = [];
    var sieve = new Array( max );
    for( var i = 0;  i < max;  i++ ) {
        sieve[i] = true;
    }
    for( var p = 2;  p < max;  p++ ) {
        if( sieve[p] ) {
            // p is prime, save it and mark p*2, p*3, etc. as non-prime
            primes.push( p );
            for( var t = p * 2;  t < max;  t += p ) {
                sieve[t] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

var k = 20;
console.log("listPrimes(" + k + ")");
console.log(fmt(listPrimes(k)));
```

**When I try to put it through I get this error:**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-235:~$ node hw2.js
listPrimes(20)

/home/ubuntu/hw2.js:22
console.log(fmt(listPrimes(k)));
            ^
ReferenceError: fmt is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/hw2.js:22:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

**I have no idea what's wrong, I'm a beginner so it may be very obvious.**

**Edit: Fixed**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
function listPrimes( max ) {
    var primes = [];
    var sieve = new Array( max );
    for( var i = 0;  i < max;  i++ ) {
        sieve[i] = true;
    }
    for( var p = 2;  p < max;  p++ ) {
        if( sieve[p] ) {
            // p is prime, save it and mark p*2, p*3, etc. as non-prime
            primes.push( p );
            for( var t = p * 2;  t < max;  t += p ) {
                sieve[t] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

var k = 100;
console.log("listPrimes(" + k + "):" + listPrimes(k));
```

**Returns:**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-235:~$ node hw2.js
listPrimes(100):2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97
```

Comment: The `fmt` function is not defined anywhere.

Comment: For reference: https://npmjs.org/package/fmt and http://nodetoolbox.com/packages/fmt

Comment: Thanks, I think that fixed it, how would I make it export the prime numbers to a text file? I thought this would accomplish that but I'm getting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the two lines

```
console.log("listPrimes(" + k + ")");
console.log(fmt(listPrimes(k)));
```

to the single line

```
console.log("listPrimes(" + k + "): " + listPrimes(k).join(", "));
```

You don't need `fmt` and anyway that's not how you would use it...

**edited** just realized that `listPrimes` returns an array, not a single value. Hence added the `join` - it allows me to put "comma, space" between the numbers which looks a bit nicer than all the digits crammed together.

As for your "afterquestion" - not sure what you are doing wrong.  The following is what happens on my machine (having copied your file `hw2.js` to a local directory):

```
bigMac:node floris$ node hw2.js 
listPrimes(100): 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
bigMac:node floris$ node hw2.js > output.txt
bigMac:node floris$ cat output.txt
listPrimes(100): 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97
bigMac:node floris$ dir
total 16
drwxr-xr-x    4 floris  floris   136 Jul  4 16:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  140 floris  floris  4760 Jul  4 16:13 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 floris  floris   561 Jul  4 16:15 hw2.js
-rw-r--r--    1 floris  floris   112 Jul  4 16:17 output.txt
bigMac:node floris$
```

As you can see, when I run the command with the `> output.txt`, the output is directed to a file. Given the error you are getting, you must be doing something different - I can't figure out from your comment what it is. Did you put the `>` in the source file, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, I think that fixed it, how would I make it export the prime numbers to a text file? I thought this would accomplish that but I'm getting nothing.

Comment: This exports "to console". Depending on your operating system, if you run your program with a `> filename` at the end, it will usually send the output to this file.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu I added '> filename' to the end and got this got this error. Do I have to create the file first or?

`ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-235:~$ node hw2.js

/home/ubuntu/hw2.js:22
> hw2.text
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3`

Comment: Can you give the exact command you typed? It looks like the error occurred during compilation rather than when you were running it.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-235:~$ node hw2.js

Comment: See my code edit. The `> output.txt` is part of the command, not part of the code itself. So - use the code you had (that worked), and invoke it with `node hw2.js > output.txt` . Does that clarify it for you?

Comment: Got it, and if I wanted my program to generate the text file how would I do that?

Comment: You will find exactly what you need by looking at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/nodejs-write-to-file). Let me know if that doesn't solve it for you. I think the third answer is best for your needs (using `stream.write`)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a function 'fmt' which you haven't defined.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, there is no function `fmt`.

Since you are returning an array, your last line may as well look like:

```
console.log(listPrimes(k).join(","));
```

*Yes, there is no sanity check on the return value of `listPrimes()` as it always returns something.*