# Write javascript variables to JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, jsonp

I have a an JSON file: example_json.json and this file looks like this:

```
{
    "timeline":
    {
        "headline":"WELCOME",
        "type":"default",
        "text":"People say stuff",
        "startDate":"10/4/2011 15:02:00",
        "date": [
            {
                "startDate":"10/4/2011 15:10:00",
            "endDate":"10/4/2011 15:55:00",
                "headline":"prvo",
                "text":"<p>dddddddddddddddd dd</p>",
                "asset":
                {

                    "caption":"yessss"
                }
            },
            {
                "startDate":"10/4/2011 17:02:00",
                "endDate":"10/4/2011 18:02:00",
                "headline":"drugo da da",
                "text":"<p>In true political fashion, his character rattles off common jargon heard from people running for office.</p>",
                "asset":
                {
                    "media":"http://youtu.be/u4XpeU9erbg",
                    "credit":"",
                    "caption":""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

so this is example of json file.

On other side I have this variables:

```
var place.name;
var zajson;
```

and: `<button>Add to timeline</button>`

Now I want when I click on button "add to timeline" to create new 'element' inside "date" with "startDate" to be: curentDateFormat in format month/day/year + zajson

and to add "headline" : place.name

How I can add this variables and create new element inside "date" in example_json.json?

Comment: how i can write this variables to example_json.json file ???

Comment: On the other side? You mean Heaven?

Comment: sorry my english is bad...

Comment: It is not clear where exactly you want to save this file. In any case, you'll need a serverside language to actually write the file to disk and only after that let the user download it.

Comment: You can't write to a file with javascript.

Comment: @adeneo [Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-nodejs)

Comment: the file already excist, just i need to add new values...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this client-side in modern browsers. For example you can use local storage (or cookie or something) to manipulate JSON dynamically and create a file using BlobBuilder.

Example:

```
window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder;
var file = new window.BlobBuilder()
```