# How to reorganize/refactor large sets of static javascript data

Tags: javascript

I have some inline-javascript containing large datasets which are hard-coded into my *PHP* site:

```js
var statsData = {
    "times"  : [1369008000,1369094400,1369180800,],
    "counts" : [49,479,516,]
};
```

I'd like to refactor my code so that my variables are served with this structure:

```js
[
    [1369008000, 49],
    [1369094400, 479],
    [1369180800, 516],
]
```

However I have many files to update - are there any tools that would help automate this process?

Comment: This is JavaScript, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is. I tagged it as PHP because I figured that's how i'd be able to parse/reorganize it.

Comment: By this do you mean it's being generated by *PHP* beforehand? - in which case you'd be as well showing us *that* code.

Comment: @Emissary no, it's not being generated - I have hundreds of pages of this javascript. Want to run it through (anything, really but assumed PHP) to reorganize it.

Comment: You're still keeping us guessing... Are we talking javascript files with nothing but valid *JS* within? If so you'd be better writing a batch script in the same language, you can run JS on the command line with [Node](http://nodejs.org/) - see [this post on how to read/write to files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2497040/1238344); combined with `eval` first then `JSON.stringify` this should cover what you need.  If on the other hand this is data mixed in with *HTML* or *PHP* or other stuff then it's a much bigger, messier, hackier task.

Comment: I have pages of this Javascript code. It is mixed with php/html. I'm just trying to make a script that i can Copy & Paste code from my saved files into an it will export it in the format I want. A nother way to word this is 
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,][1,2,3,4,5,6] how do i make change to [a,1][b,2][c,3]...?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new array then loop through the original one, and place the values according to the indexes:

```
var statsData = {"times":[1369008000,1369094400,1369180800,],"counts":[49,479,516,]};

var result = [];//Create a new array for results.
for (var i = 0; i < statsData.times.length; ++i){//Loop the original object's times property from 0 to it's length.
    result.push([statsData.times[i], statsData.counts[i]]);//Push a new array to the result array in the new order that will contain the original values you acces throught the index in the loop variable.
}

console.log(result);
```

Also in your code you have two start `[` in your object's `counts` attribute but only one `]` closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on from the comments; Trying to parse JS from a mix of *PHP/HTML* is horrible so if you are prepared to do some copying and pasting then - if it were me - I'd opt for a simple command-line tool.  As your Javascript won't validate as *JSON* it doesn't make much sense to try and parse it in any other language.

I've knocked up a quick script to work with your current example *(I'll leave it up to you to extend it further as needed)*.  To run it you will need to install [**Node.js**](http://nodejs.org/)

Next, save the following where ever you like to organise files - lets call it **statsData.js**:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function(data){
    try { 
        eval(data+';global.data=statsData');
        processData(); 
    } catch(e) {
        process.stdout.write('Error: Invalid Javascript\n');
    }
});

function processData(){
    try {
        var i, out = [];
        while(i = data.times.shift())
            out.push([i, data.counts.shift()||0]);
        process.stdout.write('var statsData='+JSON.stringify(out)+';\n');
    } catch(e) {
        process.stdout.write('Error: Unexpected Javascript\n');
    }
}
```

Now you have a CLI tool that works with standard `I/O`, to use it open a terminal window and run:

```
$ node path/to/statsData.js
```

It will then sit and wait for you to copy and paste valid javascript statements into the terminal, otherwise you could always pipe the input stream from a file where you have copied and pasted your *JS* to:

```
$ cat inputFile.js | node path/to/statsData.js > outputFile.js
```

`cat` is a unix command - if you are working on a windows machine I think the equivalent is `type` - but I'm unable to test that right now.