# How to use fs.write function of node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using node.js for the first time. I want to write a file using the fs.write function. I have taken reference from its file system docs. Its syntax is like this:
fs.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, callback)

I know how to use fd, buffer and callback in this, but I am not able to figure out how to pass offset, length and position.

Should they be some integers or string?... or what? I am not able to find out.

Comment: Please paste some code to check.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`offset` and `length` are integers referring to positions of the Buffer. `offset` is where in the Buffer should we write from; `length` is how many bytes should be written.

So, as an example, if you had a Buffer with data `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, you could write `cdef` with `offset: 2, length: 4`.

`position` is an integer for where in the file the data should be written. So, if you have an existing file, you could overwrite part of it by setting the position to something between the beginning and the end.

Comment: var wbuffer=new Buffer('message');
   var bufferPosition=0,
   bufferLength=wbuffer.length,
   filePosition=null;

   fs.write('public/file1.txt',wbuffer,bufferPosition,bufferLength,filePosition,function(err,written) {
           console.log(err);
           res.end();
    });  I am using it as above but still not able to write file. An error is coming saying bad argument.

Comment: The first argument should be a file descriptor, that is, the result of `fs.open(filename, "w", callback)`. `fs.write` does support passing a string as the first argument.