# Exit Node Process After Successful fs.appendFile

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm having trouble create processes in parallel with Node while exiting when they're done with a simple HTTP GET request.  I've noticed that if I fire a process.exit() inside of a callback for appendFile, some files will not be created or appended in a Node cluster setup.  Ideally, the way below is how I would like to fire events since the process is exited as soon as the job is done:

```
var rp = require("request-promise");
    config = require("./config"),
    cluster = require("cluster"),
    os = require("os"),
    fs = require("fs");

var keywordArray = [
    'keyword1',
    'keyword2',
    ...
];

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    var numCPUs = os.cpus().length;
    var clusterDivision = Math.ceil(keywordArray.length/numCPUs);

    // Reset the json if previously set
    keywordArray.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
        fs.unlink(config.dataDirectory + arrayItem + '.json', function(err) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            console.log('successfully unlinked ' + arrayItem + '.json from ' + config.dataDirectory);
        });
    });

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    // Seperate the array out evenly for each worker
    for (var j=1;j<=numCPUs;j++) {
        var tempArray = [];
        var removed = keywordArray.splice(0, clusterDivision);
        if (removed.length > 0) {
            // The array contains something so let's do something with the keyword
            console.log('creating a worker');
            cluster.fork().send(removed);
        } else {
            // We don't need a cluster here
        }
    }

    process.on('exit', function() {
        console.log('exited');
    });

} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
    //  Code to run if we're in a worker process

    // Send the object we created above from variables so they're available to the workers
    process.on('message', function(seperatedArrayItem) {

        seperatedArrayItem.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
            function radarRequest(err, response, body) {
                var responseBody = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(arrayItem); 
                fs.appendFileSync(config.dataDirectory + arrayItem + '.json', JSON.stringify(responseBody.results, null, '\t'), function (err) {
                    if (err) console.err(err);
                    console.log('success writing file');
                });
            }

            rp({
                url: config.radarSearchURI + 
                '?key='+ config.apiKey + 
                '&location=' + config.latitude + ',' + config.longitude + 
                '&radius=' + config.searchRadius + 
                '&keyword=' + arrayItem, headers: config.headers
            }, radarRequest);
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            process.exit(0);
        }, 5000);
    });
}
```

The only way I can make sure all files are properly appended is by using a Timeout, which is exactly what I don't want to - and shouldn't - do.  Is there another way I can ensure an appendFile has happened successfully and **then** kill the node process?  Here's a way that works (assuming the process doesn't take longer than 5 seconds):

```
    process.on('message', function(seperatedArrayItem) {

    seperatedArrayItem.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
        function radarRequest(err, response, body) {
            var responseBody = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(arrayItem); 
            fs.appendFile(config.dataDirectory + arrayItem + '.json', JSON.stringify(responseBody.results, null, '\t'), function (err) {
                if (err) console.err(err)
                console.log('success writing file');
            });
        }

        rp({
            url: config.radarSearchURI + 
            '?key='+ config.apiKey + 
            '&location=' + config.latitude + ',' + config.longitude + 
            '&radius=' + config.searchRadius + 
            '&keyword=' + arrayItem, headers: config.headers
        }, radarRequest);
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        process.exit(0);
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Checkout if [writing with streams help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js/6958773#6958773) or writeSync

Comment: Why is calling `process.exit` necessary in this case? It should exit when all of the child processes are closed.

Comment: They never all exit, as I split process up with the cluster.  I'll want to do more clustered actions after I get these so I want to make sure they're closed before creating new ones.  Is that no how I should do it?

Comment: @laggingreflex write streams will also perform with the same result.  They work perfectly however I really want to close the process once this is complete as I intend on performing more actions once I have these files created.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426394/why-does-this-node-script-exit-in-node-0-12-but-not-in-0-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an async flow control module like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) to kill the process after all files are written. I'd also recomment `cluster.worker.disconnect()` so that the node process will simple exit gracefully, but that isn't a requirement.

```
async.forEach(seperatedArrayItem, function(item, done){
    // append file and call 'done' when it is written.

}, function(){
    // Will be called when all item 'done' functions have been called.
    cluster.worker.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This was really bogging me down the last few days.  The key was tying into async's `done()`; thanks for the overview on it.  Can you expand more on why you recommend `cluster.order.disconnect()` over `process.exit(0)`?

Comment: Node processes automatically exit when they have nothing left to do in their event loop, so `.disconnect` tells the worker to stop talking to the master process, and with that disconnected, the process has nothing else keeping it alive.

Answer (score 2):

Node `fs.appendFile( ... )` is an *asynchronous* function. So it expects us to pass a *callback* for we know it has finished its main operation, to inform us of some error occurred, or another purpose.

This means we need to call Node `process.exit( ... )` in the scope of the provided callback. I've written this code to test:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

function jsonValue(obj) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t');
}

fs.appendFile('file.json', jsonValue(['t', 'e', 's', 't']), function(error) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    console.log('success writing file');  // no error, so log...
    process.exit();                       // and exit right now
    console.log('exited?');               // this will not be printed
});
```

Well, it worked as defined.

Other way it works is to use the synchronous version of `fs.appendFile( ... )` and call `process.exit()` in a sequential way:

```
fs.appendFileSync('file.json', jsonValue(['t', 'e', 's', 't']));

console.log('success writing file'); // no error (I hope so =), so log...
process.exit(); // and exit right now
console.log('exited?'); // this will not be printed
```

This is clean code and works, but you lose the robustness and convenience gained with the callback...