# Saving JSON in Electron

Tags: javascript, json, electron

I am building an app using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). In this app, I am building a data structure using JSON. My data structure looks like this:

```
{
  items: [
    { id:1, name:'football' },
    { id:2, name:'soccer ball' },
    { id:3, name:'basketball' }
  ]
}
```

I want to save this JSON to a file called "data.json". I want to save it to a file because I want to load the next time the application starts. My challenge is, I do not know how to save the data. In fact, I'm not sure *where* I should even save the file. Do I save it in the same directory as the app? Or is there some cross-platform approach I should use?

Currently, I have the following:

```
saveClick: function() {
  var json = JSON.stringify(this.data);
  // assume json matches the JSON provided above.
  // Now, I'm not sure how to actually save the file.
}
```

So, how / where do I save JSON to the local file system for use at a later time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js  - This might help you. Just replace the path to `data.json` and the contents with your `json` variable

Comment: Why don't you just use Local Storage?

Comment: As in the HTML 5 local storage API?

Comment: A user can easily clear browser data, and unintentionally lose the apps data too.

Comment: No they can't, your app's "Browser data" is completely separate from Google Chrome

Comment: iirc localstorage is only available from renderer process

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Electron lacks an easy way to persist and read user settings for your application. [electron-json-storage](https://github.com/jviotti/electron-json-storage) implements an API somehow similar to `localStorage` to write and read JSON objects to/from the operating system application data directory, as defined by `app.getPath('userData')`.

Comment: Just one information about this in electron-json-storage. It use const os = require('os'); and storage.setDataPath(os.tmpdir()); But nothing others information about location in local app for example...

Answer (score 6):

Electron uses node.js as its core. You can use the following:

```
var fs = require("fs");
read_file = function(path){
     return fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
}

write_file = function(path, output){
    fs.writeFileSync(path, output);
}
```

For `write_file()`, you can either pass `"document.txt"` as the path and it will write it to the same directory the html file it was run from. You can also put in a full path like `"C:/Users/usern/document.txt"` and it will write to the specific location you want.

Also, you can choose any file extention you want, (ie. ".txt", ".js", ".json", etc.). You can even make up your own!

Comment: When I used this approach, yes the file is written but the app resets and restarts due to an issue related to `nodemon` *https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1509*

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple library that you can use, with a simple interface, it also creates subdirectories and works with promises/callbacks.
    it will save the data into app.getPath("appData") as the root folder.

https://github.com/ran-y/electron-storage

### Installation

`$ npm install --save electron-storage`

#### usage

`const storage = require('electron-storage');`

#### API

```
storage.get(filePath, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

storage.get(filePath)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });

storage.set(filePath, data, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    });

storage.set(filePath, data)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
`const fs = require('fs');

let student = { 
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 23, 
    gender: 'Male',
    department: 'English',
    car: 'Honda' 
};
 
let data = JSON.stringify(student, null, 2);

fs.writeFile('student-3.json', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Data written to file');
});

console.log('This is after the write call');`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple steps:
**Step 1**: 
As of version 5, the default for nodeIntegration changed from true to false. You can enable it when creating the Browser Window:

```
const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 1000,
     height: 800,
     webPreferences: {
       nodeIntegration: true,
       contextIsolation: false,
     }
  })
}
```

**Step 2**:

```
function writetofile() {
        let configsettings = {
          break: output.innerHTML,
          alwaysonoff: toggleoutput.innerHTML,
        };

        let settings_data = JSON.stringify(configsettings, null, 2);

        const fs = require("fs");

        fs.writeFileSync("assets/configs/settings.json", settings_data);
      }
```