# Electron - How to persist offline data and sync between different app installation

Tags: database, websocket, electron, offline

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55184361/12912441), I want to use an offline first db inside my electron app. I nedd that the users are not able to directly modify the database, but they can only read data using the UI. The data needs to be synced with a master remote client app that will add and modify data. Can anyone suggest me a good database library to do this?I have a pusher account and an heroku one, that can be used to pass the data between the clients, but first I need a way to store them into the app

Comment: To clarify: You want the user to enter data offline, and when the user gets access to internet, it should sync with a database? You might want to look at ORM systems for Node.js, like https://typeorm.io/#/ or https://sequelize.org/

Comment: I need to save the data offline and at the same time, have the possibility to sync them with a central db that will be stored from a main desktop app