# How to upload files using req.files.map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I copied a code from the net that upload files and I have accidentally deleted something but I don't remember what it was, my code is as follows :

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/upload', upload.array('files'), function (req, res, next) {

var uploadPromises = req.files.map(function (file) {

});

return Promise.all(uploadPromises);
});
```

Can someone please try to figure out  what was inside uploadPromises function  in order to have my upload worked

Comment: Couldn't you find it in the net again ?

Comment: no , I have been looking for 2 days but to no avail

Comment: Begin with [`return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { ... });`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Beyond that, it depends on what you want done with the files, but call either `resolve()` (for success) or `reject()` (for an error).

Comment: _"Can someone please try to figure out what was inside uploadPromises function in order to have my upload worked"_ Tried `return file`?

Comment: I just want to store it in my /uploads directory , I can read   my file   using the argument  'file' from my function but it's not uploaded

Comment: Try `return Promise.resolve(file)`

Comment: I tried multer's DiskStorage (destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/uploads/') })   and I get that  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/uploads/2413fbf2ba2379ed149d3d5f4fb1ca02'

Comment: `MemoryStorage` adds a [`buffer` to each `file` object](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#api) that you can [write to a file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js). Note that you'll have to determine the full path to the `uploads` directory. The file system module doesn't work with URL paths. (For example, if `uploads` is being served by `express.static(__dirname + '/public')`, then it's at `__dirname + '/public/uploads'`).