# How to write to json file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have json file as

```
{
    "username1": "user1",
    "password1": "***",

    "username2": "user2",
    "password2": "****",

    "username3": "user3",
    "password3": "*****"
}
```

I am reading my file like this :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var contents = fs.readFileSync('./actions/writeTo.json');
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);            
console.log(jsonContent.username2);
```

But I am not able to figure out how to write to this file, say I want to update username3. How do i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing files in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Comment: You can simply use JSON.stringify

Comment: title could use a change to "How to write to JSON in node.js"

Answer (score 2):

You do exactly the opposite of what you do to read it.

You use `JSON.stringify` to turn your data structure into JSON. Then you use `fs.writeFile` to write it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var contents = fs.readFileSync('./actions/writeTo.json');
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);            
console.log(jsonContent.username2);

jsonContent.username3 = 'Changed';
jsonContent.username4 = 'New User';

var dest = '../file.json';

var fd = fs.createWriteStream(dest, {
    flags: 'w',
    autoClose: true
});

fd.write(JSON.stringify(jsonContent));
fd.end('\n');
fd.on('finish', () => {
    //Handle success
}).on('error', (err) => { // Handle errors
    fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
});
```

Comment: what if I want to write one more variable into this json?

Comment: Anything you can do. Just change the object and write it. Look edited code

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, I hope this is just for educational purposes, and you do not plan to manage user accounts this way, storing plaintext passwords in a json file.

Second, you seem to misuse the structure of JSON. Why to have `user1`, `user2`, `user3` keys when you can have an array? It would be much better if you'd arrange this data like this:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "username": "Alice",
            "anything-but-not-plaintext-password": "Puppies and kittens"
        },
        {
            "username": "Bob",
            "anything-but-not-plaintext-password": "Cheese nuggets"
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, you can write a json to a file in nodejs using [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsonContent = {}; // Here is your loader and modifier code
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonContent, null, 4); // Pretty printed
fs.writeFileSync("./actions/writeTo.json", jsonString);
```

But still, **this is how you must not handle user credentials**. Here is a pretty good tutorial on the topic: [Node.js authentication series: Passport local strategy using email and password.](http://blog.robertonodi.me/node-authentication-series-email-and-password/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as below:

```
jsonContent.username3 = 'NewUsername';

var body = JSON.stringify(jsonContent);
var localPath = './actions/writeTo.json';
fs.writeFile(localPath,body,function(err){});
```

Answer (score 0):

do `npm install jsonfile`

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');  
var config = require('../support/config.json');  

function writeToConfig(name, fileObj) {  

fileObj.username3 = name;
//console.log('This is to WriteFile Stringified fileObj:' +'\n\n' + JSON.stringify(fileObj) + '\n\n');

jsonfile.writeFile(filePath, fileObj, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});
}
```

Now you can use this function and call it as

```
writeToConfig(finalRandomName, config);
```