# Insert HTML code into another file using PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Well, i'm very new to Javascript and PHP, and I have a problem.

The idea: I want to do some post area, where in a single PHP page people will fill a form and it will create a little bootstrap panel. Don't worry about multiple pages, it's like a... wall.
Example:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">My message</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <h6>This is a test!</h6>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know exactly how to do this. What i think is that in another page, there will be a form receiving the html contents for the panel title and body and then the PHP code will create html code [not a file] using this text and will put them in another file.

**EDIT**: As you can see in the comments, i'll have to use PHP and mySQL. I'm still not sure on how to do that.

Comment: Do you need to save the file ? or just open a new page and when user leave it, all gone ?

Comment: @A.Rossi Well, as i said, it is like a wall. The "posts" will keep in the place where they should be. And about the post page, it should remain there.

Comment: Someone tell me if i'm wrong, but i think you need a server side for this, with a databse to store all your posts

Comment: @A.Rossi Really? Can't you edit an external file or create a function with javascript/jQuery?

Comment: no, javascript doesn't allow to write in external file. You can create a file but not edit

Comment: you need `ajax` and some server-side language like `php` and `database` to achieve this..

Comment: Ok. Basically, I need PHP to do this?

Comment: Yup, php / mysql is the best for a beginner i think.

Comment: You can also do it with nodejs if you're more familiar with javascript, and don't want to learn PHP

Comment: @AmirTalic I know PHP, i just preffer Javascript. I always use PHP, wanted to do something different

Comment: @MucaP if you want do something else, try JSP or nodejs as he said

Comment: @A.Rossi Ok, but well, node is something i really don't know. How can i use it in this example?

Comment: I never used it, i have really no idea

Comment: @AmirTalic Do you?

Comment: this link shows how to create a nodejs external file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js               This is a really simple example, if you want something a bit more complicated, you can find a lot more all around the internet.

Comment: @AmirTalic probably won't use it, as it is not compatible with my host. Will stick with PHP.

Comment: @AmirTalic But how would i use mySQL to store the posts? It would require the hole HTML code...

Comment: This is where templating engines come into play, using something like jade in conjunction with nodejs you'd be able to make it work just like it works in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i made this for you. The following is just for give you a start, the code is not correctly written, but it will give you a way to start your "project".

Firstly, create your database for storage your post, as follow :

```
TABLE_POST
title
content
date
autor
```

Then **wall.php** :

Start your file by getting with a query, all existing post in your database :

```
var post_list = "select id, pseudo, title, date, autor from table_post";
```

Once you have it, display it as you want :

```
<div>
foreach (post in post_list) {
echo "<div>";
echo "<h1>".post["title"]."</h1>";
echo "<p>".post["content"]."</p>";
      ...
echo "</div>";
}
</div>
```

In an other page, you can have your form : 
**form.php**

```
<form id='myform' method='post' action='add_post.php'>
<input type='text' id='title'/>
<input type='text id='content' />
<input type='text' id='autor' />
<input type='submit' value='Post it !'>
</form>
```

And in an other page, you can have the function to insert in the database :

**add_post.php**

```
insert into table_post VALUES ($_POST["title"], $_POST["content"], NOW(), $_POST["autor"]);
```

I repeat, i just give a structure for your achievement, i didn't provide a correct syntaxe of the code.
Hope it can help you

Comment: Thank you! Well, a little too much, it's a lot simpler, no date or author, but that helps. Thank You!