# fs: replace file contents by another file content

Tags: node.js, file, filesystems, fs

Given the following files:

hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

project-a.hosts

```
127.0.0.1 project-a
```

project-b.hosts

```
127.0.0.1 project-b
```

What is the easiest way to replace the hosts file contents by another given file, via FS in Node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using the `fs` module in node.js. Here are two ways of doing it, one using async functions and the other using their sync analogs.
This is as simple as it will get.

I would highly recommend you search StackOverflow more thoroughly before asking questions, since this sort of question is extremely common. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js) for example...

```
const fs = require('fs');

// async
function replaceContents(file, replacement, cb) {

  fs.readFile(replacement, (err, contents) => {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    fs.writeFile(file, contents, cb);
  });

}

// replace contents of file 'b' with contents of 'a'
// print 'done' when done
replaceContents('b', 'a', err => {
  if (err) {
    // handle errors here
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('done');
});


// sync - not recommended

function replaceContentsSync(file, replacement) {

  var contents = fs.readFileSync(replacement);
  fs.writeFileSync(file, contents);

}

replaceContentsSync('a', 'b');
```