# i am trying to clear a txt file in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text file that has some strings in it. I am trying to clear it to put something else in it. What is the right code?

I have tried `File.Clear()` but it keeps throwing errors.

Comment: you cannot update files on computer with javascript.

Comment: What kind of javascript environment are you using? `node`?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the actual errors so that we can do more than speculate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using nodejs and not a browser (in a browser you have other means of persistence like [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), but not files), check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js) and remember, you use an in memory representation of the file, if you want an empty one you can create one anew, if you want to clear the contents on the disk you need to write an empty (or whatever content you need to write) on the disk.