# How to save xml document generated using node-elementtree?

Tags: xml, npm, elementtree

Am not sure,but am not able to save the xml generated using 
  [node-elementtree](https://github.com/racker/node-elementtree/blob/master/README.md). Am new to nodejs , any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible dup. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js.

Comment: Am tried it, xml file is generated but no content. It is showing 0kb

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].