# Upload a string as file

Tags: node.js, http, file-upload, upload, unirest

How can I upload a string as a file, with an http post request using `node.js`?

Here is what I tried:

```
 var unirest = require('unirest');
    unirest.post('127.0.0.1/upload')
     .headers({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
     .attach('file', 'test.txt', 'some text in file') // Attachment
    .end(function (response) {
       console.log(response.body);
    });
```

but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a file from the local file system. So I advise

1. you [create the file locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "some text in file", function(err) {
       if(err) { return console.log(err);  }
       console.log("The file was saved!");
   });
   ```
2. send the file

   ```
   var unirest = require('unirest');
   unirest.post('127.0.0.1/upload')
       .headers({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
       .attach('file', '/tmp/test') 
       .end(function (response) {
          console.log(response.body);
       });
   ```

Comment: Isn't there a way to upload a string without writing to a file first?