# How to save a JSON file using Blob in JS without HTML

Tags: javascript, json, file, blob

I just want to store my json data in a file in a particular directory using JS. I can not see the created file using the following code.

```
    var jsonse = JSON.stringify(submitted);
    var blob = new Blob([jsonse], {type: "application/json"});
    var file = new File([blob], "" + workerID + ".json")
```

JS Documentation Link would also suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not using a web browser which cannot write to your file system for, hopefully obvious (another question), security reasons.

You can redirect output from your script to a file.

`node yourfile.js > output_file.json`

Or you can use the [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).

[Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

```
// note jsonse is the json blob
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", jsonse, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function