# Run JavaScript with a Batch file

Tags: javascript, batch-file

for a project I need to load and then run a JavaScript script using Batch.
My JavaScript script write "Website visited" to a file on my server each time that I visit my website. What I want to do is to call "http://.../js/myscript.js" with Batch in order to run this code as if I visit the URL from the browser.

Do you know how can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

You could write a JS script, that you execute with node, which fetches contents of the script from the url as a string and executes it with eval().

Comment: Thank you! but, are there other option?

Comment: You can not execute Javascript without node or a browser. You can however call the execution of your JS file from a batch file, if that is your problem.

Comment: What do you mean to "call the execution of your JS file from a batch file"? To open a browser tab?

Comment: Well, either execute a js script with node or open a browser and instruct it to go to that specific url with a command.

Comment: I would like to do it without opening a browser. So, do I need to install node.js on my server?

Comment: You have to install node wherever you want to execute the batch file. If you want to execute it on a server, then yes.

Comment: But the batch file is executed on my PC

Comment: Then you have to install it on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just do a regular start up batch.
Like @echo off
dir C://user/admin

start myscript.js

exit

You can also use a file that runs your js file in commnd line, it will be the same as node I'd assume