# How to do log when user login to myapp and write log to text.log

Tags: node.js, express

I want to do log when user log in to my app by get client ip, server ip, username, start time, end time write to text file [YY-MM-DD.log]. my app use node.js

Comment: You need to give us some code, or at least describe your libraries and what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Comment: All these information can be found in the documentations of Node.js...

Comment: @alex-rokabilis What do you recommend about libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for making organized logs in nodejs you can use  [log4js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js) . You can also build a new file with the current date name in your log directory and put your logs in it which this can be a help:  [write files in node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)