# Save submit input to a separate txt file

Tags: javascript, html

I have couple of **`select tags`** that generate an array. Until now I was just logging the array on the console when pressing **SUBMIT button** but now I want to save them on a **separate text file**.

**My main.html:**

```
 <form method="POST" action="/submit">
         <select name="rank" size="1" required >
                    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Rank</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                  </select>
  <div class="submit-holder">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
  </div>
 </form>
```

**My app.js:**

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body.rank);
});
```

**Thank you very much in advance!**

Comment: you need to use a backend language for that  you cant do that with js

Comment: By the looks of `app.post` it seems you are using Node with Express? If you are using Node you can use the [filesystem API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) to write your files. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js) post touches on the filesystem API and how to use it.

Comment: Where do you want to save the text file with the array data? .. And for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this to save data using `blob` and `FileServer.js`: https://redstapler.co/generate-text-file-javascript/