# Node - How to write a typed array to a binary file with a specified endianness

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, endianness, typed-arrays

I have a typed array and I want to write it to a binary file. I need it to be in big-endian byte order but I might not (usually won't be) on a big-endian machine. How do I get from my typed array to the binary file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may know, the way to enforce endianness in javascript is with the [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) view. Once you've created a `DataView` view of your buffer, you can set and get the data from it in either big-endian or little-endian byte order.

Here's an example of turning a typed array (which may be in little- or big-endian byte order) into a Uint8Array (equivalent to Node's 'file' Buffer) in big-endian byte order. Notice that since the `dataView` is a just a view of the underlying buffer, the original array `arr` is now byte-swapped and we will write **it** to the file.

```
arr = new Float32Array([42]) // one value
dataView = new DataView(arr.buffer)
dataView.setFloat32(0, arr[0], false /* big-endian */)
buf = new Uint8Array(arr.buffer)
```

Now you can pass that Array into a node file-writing method since `Uint8Array` is compatible with Node's `Buffer` object. For example, if you already had opened a file and had the `fd` for it, then you could do something like this:

```
fs.writeSync(fd, buf)
```

For the sake of completeness, here's example code which handles the loop you would actually use with Float32-type data:

```
arr = new Float32Array([...]) // some initial data
...
dataView = new DataView(arr.buffer)
byteNum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  dataView.setFloat32(byteNum, arr[i]);
  byteNum += Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
}

buf = new Uint8Array(arr.buffer)
fs.writeSync(fd, buf)
```

Note in the above that I didn't pass `false` to `setFloat32` because that's the default.

---

(For more details on the writing part of this see: [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js))

Comment: So where is the "specified endianness"? Is this "big-endian" or "little-endian", and how do you actually switch between the two? Because this is the title of your self answered question, yet I see nothing in the answer given which mentions any change of the byte-order.

Comment: The `set` and `get` methods on a `DataView` are specified in the last argument of the method. `false` means big-endian, and `true` means little-endian. See the docs on [setFloat32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setFloat32) for example.