# How do I save large files in Electron?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, electron

I am building an app with Electron that searches through a JSON object with Elasticlunr and prints to the HTML page. The JSON file is about 9 MB. The object needs to be loaded only once the first time the app starts. How can I store and retrieve this JSON object?

I have tried:

- Saving the object as the export of a JS file and importing into the window's main Javascript file
- Electron-storage and Electron-json-storage don't seem to be for such large files

Comment: Have you tried the native modules 'fs" ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js

Comment: The file needs to be used on the client-side. I can't use 'fs' there. Or can I?

Comment: You can. Electron comes with nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Node's native `fs` module to save onto the client's computer as a stringified version.

Another thing you could do is use something like `sqlite` to set up a local database on the user's computer if you plan on doing any querying of that JSON.

Comment: this seems to hit node heap limitations very quickly.