# How to save an array of strings to a JSON file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

How can I save an array of strings to a `JSON` file in **Node.js**:

```js
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
```

*example.json*

```json
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e", 
  "f",
  "g",
  "h"
]
```

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js#2497040 useful, using `JSON.stringify` to turn the JSON object into a string (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Node js you can do like this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
const jsonContent = JSON.stringify(alphabet);

fs.writeFile("./alphabet.json", jsonContent, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```