# unable to create array from multiple files data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've 2 files as below.

**f1.json**

```
{
"name":"user1"
}
```

**f2.json**

```
{
"name":"user2"
}
```

and here is my code snippet.

```
var fs = require("fs");

function readIt() {
  let combined = [];
  fs.readdir("jsonfiles", function (err, files) {
    files.forEach(function (file, index) {
      combined.push(fileread("jsonfiles/" + file));
    });

    fs.writeFile("test.json", combined.toString(), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
    });
  });
}

function fileread(filename) {
  var contents = fs.readFileSync(filename);
  return contents;
}

readIt();
```

when I run this, the resulting output is as below

```
{
  "name":"user1"
},
{
  "name":"user2"
}
```

but I want it to be

```
[
{
  "name":"user1"
},
{
  "name":"user2"
}
]
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save an array of strings to a JSON file in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577849/how-to-save-an-array-of-strings-to-a-json-file-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `toString()`, you should use `JSON.stringify()`.

To see their different behavior, you can try this snippet:

```js
var jsonArr = [{name: "Mia"}, {name: "Eddie"}];

// toString()
console.log(jsonArr.toString());

// JSON.stringify()
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
```

JavaScript [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) just prints out the elements of the array, excluding the array bracket, but `JSON.stringify()` prints whole Javascript object structure as a valid JSON.

As the `fs.writeFile()` in Node.JS needs/consumes buffer, so you need to store the JSON string result in a variable before using it.

```
let jsonArr = [{name: "Mia"}];
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonArr);
fs.writeFile("data.json", jsonString, (err) => ...);
```

Comment: Somehow It is returning a buffer since I'm reading from a file and doing it.

Comment: @user3872094 I have updated my answer. Please try again