# How to write to a file using Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning how to write to a file using Nodejs. I tried the below posted example, but I received the below posted error

How can I fix this error?

**Code**:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("c://NodeTest", "Hey there!", function(err) {
if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
}

console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

**Error**:

```
{ [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'c:\NodeTest']
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'c:\\NodeTest' }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you are using windows, this seems to be a file permissions error.  Try running your code as administrator (e.g. right click on the dos command prompt icon and choose "Run as administrator", then try to run your script).

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? I just tried this on my box and it worked.

Comment: Not downvoter, but I think this is bad advice in general. "I'm unfamiliar" being met with "add sudo" or similar feels like a recipe for problems.

Comment: @Fissure King - Thanks for the feedback.  I gave a windows specific answer because the OP used "c://" in the file path, which was a clear indicator they were on windows.  Based on your feedback, however, I edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to access that file. Try running as administrator or manually changing the permissions on the file