# Write javascript array elements to file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to have a node js script write some coordinates to a csv file for use in a Newman CLI script. I have the following:

```
const axios = require('axios');
var move_decimal = require('move-decimal-point');
var sLat = 45.029830;
var sLon = -93.400891;
var eLat = 45.069523;
var eLon = -94.286001;
var arrLatLon = []

axios.get('http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/' + sLon + ',' + sLat + ';' + eLon + ',' + eLat + '?steps=true')
.then(function (response) {
    for (let i = 0; i < response.data.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {
        //console.log(response.data)
        for (let ii = 0; ii < response.data.routes[0].legs[i].steps.length; ii++) {
            //console.log('leg ' + i + " - step " + ii + ": " + response.data.routes[0].legs[i].steps[ii].maneuver.location[1] + "," + response.data.routes[0].legs[i].steps[ii].maneuver.location[0]);

            // Declaring Latitude as 'n' & Longitude as 'nn' for decimal calculations
            var n = response.data.routes[0].legs[i].steps[ii].maneuver.location[1]
            var nn = response.data.routes[0].legs[i].steps[ii].maneuver.location[0]

            // Latitude calculatiuons to make 'lat' values API friendly
            var y = move_decimal(n, 6)
            var p = Math.trunc(y);

            // Longitude calculations to make 'lon' values API friendly
            var yy = move_decimal(nn, 6)
            var pp = Math.trunc(yy);

            arrLatLon.push(p +  "," + pp);
        }
        console.log(arrLatLon)
    }
})
```

I have been looking through and trying numerous different tutorials/code snippets regarding writing the array elements from `arrLatLon` to an output file on my local machine, but none have been successful. The current code outputs the lat,lon correctly, `console.log(arrLatLon)` outputs:

```
[ '45029830,-93400894',
  '44982812,-93400740',
  '44977444,-93400530',
  '44973116,-93410884',
  '44971101,-93450400',
  '45035514,-93766885',
  '45035610,-93766886',
  '45081631,-94286752',
  '45070849,-94282026' ]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look into the node fs module... https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: Oh just saw the node.js tag...whoops. Not sure why you're using axios server-side.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts This is running on a client-side machine not the server-side

Comment: Let me rephrase: I'm not sure why you're using axios _in Node.js_.

Comment: @SakoBu I have tried different variations of fs.createFileStream and fs.writeFile(Sync) etc and the file is empty every time. It's getting "updated" as np++ alerts saying the file has changed; however, its still blank.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Noted, but axios is not the issue.

Comment: @ClintT might want to make sure your node process has the proper permissions to write a file. _And that you're performing the `fs` write in the callback of the axios request._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nodejs you can easily write files using the `fs` module

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

in your case you can simply do something like

```
const fs = require('fs');
// I'm converting your array in a string on which every value is
// separated by a new line character
const output = arrLatLon.join("\n");

// write the output at /tmp/test
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", output, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Let me forward you to this question for more information [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help with this, I apparently was close before reaching out, but was missing the join on newline. Thanks for the help.

Comment: np! It's a pleasure @ClintT