# How to download files in azure blob storage into local folder using node js

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

I am using node js to download azure blob storage files into our local machine. I am able to download it into my project path but not able to download into my local machine. I am using html, Express,and node js. Currently working on localhost only. How to download ?

Below is the code that i am using to download blob file to local folder.

```
app.get("/downloadImage", function (req, res) {
    var fileName = req.query.fileName;
    var downloadedImageName = util.format('CopyOf%s', fileName);
    blobService.getBlobToLocalFile(containerName, fileName, downloadedImageName, function (error, serverBlob) {
    });
});
```

I am able to to download it to my project folder but i want to download it to my downloads folder. Please help me on this ?

Comment: I think we need some more information here. Is the server running on your local computer, or are you making the request to a different machine?
Depending on the answer, it might be useful to know the file extension too.

Comment: Yes i am running my node js solution on local computer. I am trying to download pdf and image files from azure blob storage.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

To download a file from Azure blob storage

- ConnectionString: Connection string to blob storage
- blobContainer: Blob Container Name
- sourceFile: Name of file in container i.e sample-file.zip
- destinationFilePath: Path to save file i.e `${appRoot}/download/${sourceFile}`

```js
const azure = require('azure-storage');

async function downloadFromBlob(
    connectionString,
    blobContainer,
    sourceFile,
    destinationFilePath,
  ) {
    logger.info('Downloading file from blob');
    const blobService = azure.createBlobService(connectionString);
    const blobName = blobContainer;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      blobService.getBlobToLocalFile(blobName, sourceFile, destinationFilePath, (error, serverBlob) => {
        if (!error) {
          logger.info(`File downloaded successfully. ${destinationFilePath}`);
          resolve(serverBlob);
        }
        logger.info(`An error occured while downloading a file. ${error}`);
        reject(serverBlob);
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference of the method [`blobService.getBlobToLocalFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/azurestorage.services.blob.blobservice.blobservice?view=azure-node-latest#getblobtolocalfile-string--string--string--errororresult-blobresult--), as below, the value of parameter `localFileName` should be the local file path with related dir path.

> **localFileName** string **The local path to the file to be downloaded**.

So I created a directory named `downloadImages` and changed your code as below.

```
var downloadDirPath = 'downloadImages'; // Or the absolute dir path like `D:/downloadImages`

app.get("/downloadImage", function (req, res) {
    var fileName = req.query.fileName;
    var downloadedImageName = util.format('%s/CopyOf%s', path, fileName);
    blobService.getBlobToLocalFile(containerName, fileName, downloadedImageName, function (error, serverBlob) {
    });
});
```

It works for me, the image file was downloaded into my `downloadImages` directory, not under the path of my `node app.js` running.

Note: If you want to deploy it on Azure WebApp later, please must use the absolute directory path like `D:/home/site/wwwroot/<your defined directory for downloading images>`, because the related directory path is always related the path of IIS started up node.