# How can I save a file (in node.js) from memory to a specific location on the disk?

Tags: node.js, file, memory, multer, disk

I'm trying to save a file to a specific location on the server disk (using `multer`), but this location name is related to data i receive in request along with file.

I came to conclusion that I can save file in memory, and later (after some other part of code will complete, and i will have my location name generated) I will save that file to disk space. And this is where i stuck - how can I save file in node.js from object in memory to specific disk location?

This is object that i have saved in memory:

```
{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '20190221_171825.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer:
   <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 ... >,
  size: 5173060 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR via `fs` [module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = { fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '20190221_171825.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer:
   <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 ... >,
  size: 5173060 };

fs.writeFile("path/to/file", data, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

But to be honest, you should check [other relevant questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js) before asking a new one here.

Comment: Thank you (also for pointing to similar thread).
It helped me a lot!
I must made some kind of mistake earlier, because i tried to follow steps i found on stackoverflow and it didn't work. Now its working great. ;)
But there is one thing that you should change in your answer - constant named "data" should contain only value of buffer, not whole file object.

Comment: What about the issue of the 'reset' due to 'nodemon'? 
 https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1509  does this approach not restart node because it is 'watching' for file changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JIMP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) module to move or manipulate your image.