# I need to update information to a JSON file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to update by adding information to a json file that looks like

```
[{"name": "Nathan"},{"name": "Jeff"}]
```

I am currently doing this

```
const fs = require('fs');
let name = require('./test.json');

let data = JSON.parse(name);

data.push({name: 'Bob'});

name = JSON.stringify(data)
```

My desired result is to have the JSON file to look like this

```
[{"name": "Nathan"},{"name": "Jeff"},{"name": "Bob"},]
```

Comment: What about this is not working? You don't know how to re-write to the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

your code doesn't change the file, it only changes the variable containing the value of the JSON file, and don't use JSON.parse you can require it directly to the variable, then work with it as a js object.
if you want then to change the file, you can use the "fs" module in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55887717/8006569) ( and don't forget that it is asynchronous )

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the very handy [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) module, it supports a lot of operations on simple JSON files.

Here's an example:

```
const dbFileName = "db.json";

const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const adapter = new FileSync(dbFileName)
const db = low(adapter)

// Set some defaults (required if your JSON file is empty)
db.defaults({ users: [] })
.write()

// Add some users and save..
db.get('users')
.push({ id: 1, name: 'Jack Smith', dob: '1981-21-08'})
.push({ id: 2, name: 'Kim Jones', dob: '1992-14-03'})
.write()

// Show users.
const userList = db.get('users').value();
console.log("Users: ", userList);

// Find a user
console.log("Find user by name:", db.get('users').find({ name: 'Kim Jones' }).value());
```

There are others on the module page.

Answer (score 0):

first: It is not `fs` needed to import a json file. simply :

```js
let data = require('filename.json');
```

or `import` it if you are using `BABEL`.

About the string part, you can use `substr` like this:

```js
let data = [{"name": "Nathan"},{"name": "Jeff"}];

data.push({name: 'Bob'});

let name = JSON.stringify(data)
name=`${name.substr(0,name.length-1)},]`;

console.log(name);
```

Comment: Then you can write it with ```fs```