# storing info as a JSON file on a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, javascript-objects

So I have information i need to save. I am using a JavaScript object then I store the info in a JSON file.

But I want to put my project on a server and run it. but currently I am using fs to read and write data.
how would i do that on a server

Comment: So what's your web server?  If you're running Tomcat, you can use Java I/O.  If you're running Apache with PHP, you can use PHP fopen()/fwrite().   If you're running IIS, you can use .Net System.IO.  The possibilities are endless...

Comment: If you are asking about the the `path` you can use `__dirname`. And it will both locally and on server alike. Hope I got your question right

Comment: @FoggyDay I believe they're using `Node.js` as outline in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the JSON file in the server and read/write to it the same way you are doing locally, it makes no difference.

That said, I'd recommend using something like http://npmjs.com/package/json-server to make it work like an actual server API.