# How would I select a random line then delete it in a .txt?

Tags: javascript, fs

I've managaed to randomly select a line in a .txt file but I'm not sure how I would go about deleting it/removing it.

This is what I'm using to pick a random line, which works fine:

```
const data = fs2.readFileSync('./randomstuff.txt')
const splitData = data.toString().split("\n");
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * splitData.length);
const line = splitData.splice(randomNumber, 1);
```

How would I then delete "line" from the file?
Thanks guys, been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: You can overwrite the file after splicing the line out. I recommend not using `readFileSync`--it's going to block your process when it could be doing useful work while waiting for disk access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the random line from the splitData array, you need to overwrite the contents of the file

```
fs2.writeFileSync('./randomstuff.txt', splitData.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You've read the file into a string buffer and removed a "random" line from said buffer using splice, now all you have to do is write the file with the new buffer.

```
fs2.writeFileSync('./randomstuff.txt', splitData.join("\n"));
```