# (NODE JS) Getting Error : ReferenceError: fs is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-modules, web-deployment

Created a file with the name of index.js and the code is

```
var x = require("fs");
console.log("Hello");
fs.writeFileSync("text.txt","Hello");
```

and when I run it I receive an error:

```
ReferenceError: fs is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (G:\web\Node Js\index.js:3:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: You've assigned `fs` module to variable `x` do `x.writeFileSync("text.txt","Hello");`

Answer (score 2):

should be `var fs = require('fs');`

[Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js/2497040#2497040)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by mismatch of variables.
You've required the module in variable x and trying to access the module using varibale fs which is undefined.

You must use same variable name.

```
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("Hello");
fs.writeFileSync("text.txt","Hello");

or

var x = require("fs");
console.log("Hello");
x.writeFileSync("text.txt","Hello");
```