# Save data to an external file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hello, I am currently developing a website for my personal needs for which I need to be able to regularly save data in a "data.json" file, which I can then retrieve for later use. 
I then remembered that I had already used the "file sync" module of NodeJs before, but this time I can't manage to use it with my project as it doesn't seem to apply to my html files... 
I suspect that there are other easier solutions or that I must be using NodeJs wrong in this case. 
I use the sublime text editor and I work on 2 html files linked to the same script.js and style.css file 
Would you have solutions to propose to me? 
Thank you, cordially, 
Florent

Comment: What do you want to happen? Saving data is something that has been asked about many times before on Stack Overflow. Have you read those questions and found them lacking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say at the backend.

```
const htmlTxt = `
  <html>
  ...
  </html>
`
// write the file locally
fs.writeFileSync("sampleHtml.html", htmlTxt);

// read the contents of the file
console.log(fs.readFileSync("sampleHtml.html", "utf8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the File system module.

So on your nodeJS server, you would have to add:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

then create your json:

```
let jsonElement = { 
    aa: 'aa',
    test: 123,
};
let data = JSON.stringify(jsonElement);
```

And save it to file

```
fs.writeFileSync('json_file.json', data);
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html