# Write data to json file located tin a URL using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios, node-fetch

Is there a way in which I could write data to a url like *https://xenialbase.web.app/file.json* using axios or node-fetch in javscript and then display the value in that url
this is the code I tried using axios but after refreshing the link I am not being able to see that data. I even get a statuscode 200 (ok) :

```js
var axios = require("axios")
axios
  .post('https://xenialbase.web.app/file.json', {
    todo: 'Buy the milk'
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`)
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

Comment: What does _"but after refreshing the link"_ mean?

Comment: @evolutionxbox what I meant was that I want the data posted to be seen suppose I post `"a":1`  I want the JSON file to contain `"a":1` saved in it .

Comment: The code doesn't seem to attempt to save a file?

Comment: then how do I save it ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js