# NodeJs: How to save file/files from request object to folder in nodejs controller functions

Tags: node.js, express, multer

**Problem: When I try to upload files using postman, files get uploaded to the destination folder. But I want to upload files in destination folder in controller function after performing some operation**

How can I store files in the destination folder?

In controller function when I console.log(req.files) I get: [image]
**What did I do:**

- I use multer.memoryStorage() to store files in memory not in destination folder.
- And In controller function I get files in req.files

**What I want to do:**
save each files to destination folder (upload/files)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js