# Node.js append raw bytes to file

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to append 4 bytes to a raw data file.

This code would write text, but there's no guide to doing raw bytes

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('Hello World > helloworld.txt');
});
```

Comment: You can use the nodejs [buffer object](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfrombuffer) to write a buffer to file.

Comment: Would probably use a Buffer to do that. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js

Comment: `fs.appendFile()` will append bytes to the end of an existing file.

Answer (score -1):

[`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) accepts a `Buffer` as well as a string.

This example would append three `0x01` bytes to a file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', Buffer.from([0x01, 0x01, 0x01]), { flag: "a" }, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('Hello World > helloworld.txt');
});
```