# How to save and files on amazon ebs with node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node.js application using elastic beanstalk with ebs volume.
How can I save files to amazon ebs using node.js?

Does using the simple code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-to-files-in-node-js/2497040#2497040) put the file on ebs?

```
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

If it does, what is the code difference between saving the file on ebs or on the disk?

Comment: What is "amazon ebs" in you view? Elastic-Beanstalk?

Comment: @Marcin Amazon Elastic Block Store https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/

Comment: Ok, so what is your "disk" when you write "on the disk"? EBS volume is your disk. So what other "disk" do you expect to use?

Comment: @Marcin well I've thought there is regular disk. maybe i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The "disk" in your EC2 instance for your Elastic Beanstalk (EB), is just an EBS volume. There is no special other storage provided by EB for your application.

However, storing your data (e.g. images uploaded by the users) on the EB instance is a bad practice. The preferred way is to store all the date externally to your EB environment, for example in S3 or EFS filesystem.

Comment: I only want to store html files. Losing the data when I deploy a new instance is good for me because those html files might not be relevant.

Comment: @EranShmuel Is your website  static? If yes, you can host static websites on S3.

Comment: It's not a static website

Comment: @EranShmuel In that case, your "disk" is the EBS volume associated with the EC2 instance that your EB environment uses. There is nothing else special about that.